# Getting the error 1119: Access of possibly undefined property visible through a reference with static type Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am attempting to hide a symbol (Grill image) as soon as my animation loads.
Currently I am getting the error, E:\Burger Game\DragandDrop\Dragable.as, Line 4, Column 8  1119: Access of possibly undefined property visible through a reference with static type Class. As you can probably tell, I am new to flash.

```
package DragandDrop
{
    Grill.visible=false;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Dragable extends MovieClip
    {

        protected var homePos:Point;
        var totalToBowl:int =3;
        var i:int = 0;
        public function Dragable ()
        {                   
            homePos=new Point( x, y);
            buttonMode =true;
            addEventListener ( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, move);
        }

        //egg functions
        protected function move(event:MouseEvent) :void
        {           
            parent.addChild(this);
            startDrag();
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageUp)            
        }

        //item drop function

        protected function stageUp(event:MouseEvent):void
                {

                stopDrag();
                if (event.target.dropTarget != null &&dropTarget.parent.name == "Bowl")
                {
                    scaleX=scaleY=0;
                    alpha=0.5;
                    y= stage.stageHeight-height -700;
                    x=stage.stageWidth-width- 1400;
                    buttonMode=false;
                    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stageUp)
                    i++

            }if (i == totalToBowl){

            i=10
            trace(i);
            event.target.dropTarget.visible = false;


        }
        if (i==10 )
        {
            dropTarget.parent.visible = false;  
                }else{
                    returnToHome();

                }
    }

        protected function returnToHome():void
        {
            x = homePos.x;
            y= homePos.y;
        }

}
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Any help would be massively appreciated.
Many thanks,

Rob

Comment: It sounds like `Grill` is a class linked to a symbol, but `visible` is an instance property, not a class property (`static`). Where is the `Grill` instance in relation to `Dragable`? Is `Dragable` your document class?

Comment: @Rob - Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. `Grill` is a class, but it would seem you are trying to use it like an instance.  This is what it's expecting to see when used like you're doing:

   ```
   public class Grill extends MovieClip {
       public static var visible:Boolean;
   }
   ```

   But more than likely, what you need to do is work with an instance, not the class itself:

   ```
   var g:Grill = new Grill();
   g.visible = false;
   ```

   If this class is linked to a timeline instance, you'd have to use the instance name you gave it (and make sure that instance name doesn't clash with any Class names - or use `getChildByName`).
2. Assuming this is not meant to be static code, you have code outside of a function/method that will cause another error.

   In class files, all non-static functional code needs to be in a function. You need to move that line in question (Grill.visible=false) into a function.  Most likely, you want this to be the equivalent of timeline code.  So the best place to put would be this:

   ```
   public function Dragable ()
   {                   
       homePos=new Point( x, y);
       buttonMode =true;
       addEventListener ( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, move);

       //addedToStage is the best equivalent of when timeline code would run
       addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
   }

   private function addedToStage(e:Event):void {
        //where grillinstance is the instance name of your grill
        grillInstance.visible = false;
   }
   ```

Now, this assumes you have this class linked at timeline that has an instance of Grill on it.  If this is an incorrect assumption, please clarify with a comment or by updating your question.

Comment: Actually, you *can* put code outside of functions in a class, it will get [executed during class static initialization](http://blog.mesmotronic.com/index.php/p/354) (example wraps it in `{ }` but that's not necessary). There are few (if any) good reasons to do this, but the OP's code was actually valid, just not what they meant. **Otherwise this is a great answer, upvoted.**

Comment: Yes, this was assuming it's not meant to be static code. But it's a good point for clarification.